# Como pudiera llenar una lista

Tags: android, android-studio

Como pudiera llenar un ListView. Usando botón que llame a otra actividad y enesta entro los datos que quiero que se muestren en la actividad que tiene la lista.

Comment: Podrías aclarar un poco mejor que es lo que quieres? Quizas con un ejemplo?

Comment: Por favor agrega mas detalles, para entender mejor tu problema y proponerte una mejor solución